# there is ./back directory in my home directory of 1.9.3.4 Do I need it?

Tags: magento-1.8, security, magento-1.9.3.4

there is ./back directory in my public_html directory of 1.9.3.4 Do I need it?
Inside there is .back/app/Mage.php which is still old 1.8 version. Besides, the /back directory contains bunch of magento package files like skin, shell, app, media, defaults etc. I don't remember how this directory got there. Can I just delete the /back and everything inside? Is it just a simple worthless duplicate? Or does it carry any function?
It bothers me because it's contains still some old insecure 1.8 version files.
Thank you,
Maks

Comment: btw, the dates the files in the /back were modified last time range from a few months ago to few years ago. I feel like its Ok to delete everything but would like someone confirm that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no folder named *back* in the Magento CE 1.x release code root folder.

Sounds like this is a backup folder manually made by someone. It is safe to delete it.

I would keep a copy of it somewhere *just in case*.

Comment: Just did. thank you!

Comment: @MaksR I would see what it contains, if indeed there are backups. Check permissions and make sure the folder is not visible/accessible to public.

Comment: Some of them did have 644 permissions. What are the permissions that would block access to public? 666? Thanks